In my Blazor server side app: How can I start an application on the server side in the foreground (not background) with usual interface?
In my Blazor server side app I am starting an application on the server side (not on the client side) with code below. But the application is running always in background, so the normal interface window of the app cannot be seen on the server side. (I do not want to say that it cannot be seen on the client side! Sure that is never possible). Just for test purposes I want to login to the server (where my Blazor web app is running) and do some operations on the opened app.
How can I do that?
My code:
    public void OpenAppOnServer()
    {         
       Process_ServerApp = new Process               
       {
           StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
           {
               FileName = App_path,
               Arguments = "",
               UseShellExecute = false,                        
               CreateNoWindow = false,
               WindowStyle=System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
           }
       };
       Process_ServerApp.Start();
    }

